# Dynamically Changing the Field/Column Name Based on Value of Other Column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I currently have a table like the one below (I know it's kind of odd logic):
[image: Example Table]

I would like to have the columns instead show the following:
[image: Desired Result]

Since the data source I get this from automatically changes the first five columns to the appropriate year, I was hoping I could set the "Value" columns to have dynamic names based on the values found in the first five columns.

Any help would be appreciated with solving this in either DAX or Power Query.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using Power Query might be to implement some steps like:

1. Get the names of the 5 rightmost columns of the table (which should give you a list of 5 strings, all of which end in `" Value"`).
2. For each column name, trim `" Value"` from the end (which should give you a list of 5 different strings, all of which should be names of columns in your table).
3. For each trimmed column name, look up the value in the first row of that column (which should give you a list of 5 different strings, which will be the new column names).

The code below basically tries to do the above.

---

```
let
    someTable = Table.FromRows({
        {2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 123, 355, 744, 234, 685},
        {2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 59, 1129, 254, 774, 490}
    }, type table [
        PFY2 = Int64.Type,
        PFY = Int64.Type,
        CFY = Int64.Type,
        NFY = Int64.Type,
        NFY2 = Int64.Type,
        PFY2 Value = Int64.Type,
        PFY Value = Int64.Type,
        CFY Value = Int64.Type,
        NFY Value = Int64.Type,
        NFY2 Value = Int64.Type
    ]),
    oldNames = List.LastN(Table.ColumnNames(someTable), 5),
    columnsContainingNewNames = List.Transform(oldNames, each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, " Value", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd})),
    newNames = List.Transform(columnsContainingNewNames, each Text.From(Table.Column(someTable, _){0})),
    renamed = Table.RenameColumns(someTable, List.Zip({oldNames, newNames}))
in
    renamed
```

---

Some issues:

- For simplicity, I've hard coded the 5, but if your table can change (such that the columns you need to rename may not always be the last 5), then a more dynamic approach might be something like: `oldNames = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(someTable), each Text.EndsWith(_, " Value"))`. This will pick up all column names ending in `" Value"`, including any that you might not want to rename, but it's just an example and you can tweak the predicate function as necessary.
- If your table is empty, then I think you'll get an error when looking up the value in the first row (as there won't be a first row in such circumstances).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anyway to rename column dynamically

However you can have a workaround:

You can create 5 measures, using current date and figure out all the years

You can add those measures to a table/matrix and overlay it on your main table